# What is registerFallbackValue in mocktail

Tags: flutter, unit-testing

I am trying to implement **unit tests** in flutter. For this I am using **mocktail** library. I have encountered **registerFallbackValue** method but I don't seem to understand it completely from the documentation.

Could you explain it more in detail about this method?

Answer (score 2):

> In order to support argument matchers such as any() and captureAny() mocktail has to register default fallback values to return when the argument matchers are used. Out of the box, it automatically handles all primitive types, however, when using argument matchers in place of custom types developers must use registerFallbackValue() to provide a default return value. It is only required to call registerFallbackValue() once per type so it is recommended to place all registerFallbackValue() calls within setUpAll().

> Fake helps us to define types for any(). Then, we set the types in the registerFallbackValue() method. For mocking methods, we are going to use the when() method that comes with mockito and mocktail packages. It takes a method, and you can use one of thenReturn(), thenAnswer(), and thenThrow(). If your method takes any parameter, the solution is the any() method. The important part of the any() method is that it has a few pre-registered values for types such as int, String and more. But sometimes you might need more types. In this kind of situation, you need to use the registerFallbackValue() method to define.